# Valor maximo, minimo y mediana de una matriz y su index en python

Tags: python, matriz

Tengo una matriz 3x3. Se rellena con numeros random, y quiero obtener el max el min y la mediana. El max y el min, lo obtengo con `max(matriz) min(matriz)` pero para luego sacar el indice, no puedo usar `index()` ¿entonces como lo hago? Habia pensado en pasar la matriz a una lista, pero no me sale bien.

Por otra parte, la mediana de la matriz, tampoco se como hacerla, `median(matriz)` tampoco me funciona.

PD: No puedo usar librerias como numpy o pandas.

```
from random import randrange
matriz = []
#Creo una lista que luego usare para la mediana
lista = []
for i in range(3):
  matriz.append([])
  for j in range(3):
    matriz[i].append(randrange(1000,10000))
numero = []
for i in range(3):
  lista.append(matriz[i])
  print(matriz[i])
```

En este ultimo for, en la lista, no tengo los datos separados, entonces para buscar con el index() el max y min, me aparece la fila de 3 como max y min.

Comment: El ejercicio está diseñado para que no usar `min` y `max`. Tú mismo tienes que recorrer la matriz buscando esos valores. Cuando los encuentras, ya tienes sus respectivos indicies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def devolver_posicion(matriz, valor):
    j=0
    for i in matriz:
        if valor in i:
            return (j,i.index(valor))
        j+=1

def mediana(matriz):
    len_matriz = len(matriz)
    matriz_ordenada = sorted(matriz)
    indice = (len_matriz - 1) // 2

    if (len_matriz % 2):
        return (matriz_ordenada[indice],None)
    else:
        return ((matriz_ordenada[indice] + matriz_ordenada[indice + 1]) / 2.0, "La mediana fue calculada, por tanto, no tiene una posición en la matriz")

from random import randrange
matriz = []
cantidad_fila = 3
cantidad_columnas=3
#Creo una lista que luego usare para la mediana
lista = []
maximo = 999
minimo = 10001
indice_maximo = ()
indice_minimo = ()
for i in range(cantidad_fila):
    matriz.append([])
    for j in range(cantidad_columnas):
        elemento=randrange(1000,10000)
        matriz[i].append(elemento)
        if elemento > maximo:
            maximo = elemento
            indice_maximo = (i,j)
        if elemento < minimo:
            minimo = elemento
            indice_minimo = (i, j)
    lista+=matriz[i]

if len(matriz) == 0:
    print("La matriz está vacía")
else:
    print("Matriz:\n",matriz)

    print("Máximo valor de la matriz:", maximo )

    print("Primera posición en que aparece el máximo valor:", indice_maximo)

    print("Mínimo valor de la matriz:", minimo)

    print("Primera posición en que aparece el mínimo valor:", indice_minimo)

    print("Mediana de la matriz:", mediana(lista)[0])

    print(lista)
    print(sorted(lista))
    print("Primera posición en que aparece la mediana de la matriz:",mediana(lista)[1] if mediana(lista)[1] else devolver_posicion(matriz, mediana(lista)[0]))
```

El método `mediana(matriz)` devuelve el valor de la mediana y, si esta fue calculada (por ser par la cantidad de elementos de la matriz), muestra un mensaje que indica que no existe en la matriz, en el caso contrario, el segundo valor de la tupla es None.
El método `devolver_posicion(matriz, valor)` te devolverá la posición que tiene la mediana en el arreglo, pero sólo si la cantidad de elementos de la matriz es impar, porque en el caso contrario, la mediana es calculada.

Muestra cuando `cantidad_fila = 3` y `cantidad_columnas=3`:

```
Matriz:
 [[5926, 7282, 4371], [6876, 1454, 7437], [6241, 2277, 9813]]  
Máximo valor de la matriz: 9813
Primera posición en que aparece el máximo valor: (2, 2)        
Mínimo valor de la matriz: 1454
Primera posición en que aparece el mínimo valor: (1, 1)        
Mediana de la matriz: 6241
[5926, 7282, 4371, 6876, 1454, 7437, 6241, 2277, 9813]
[1454, 2277, 4371, 5926, 6241, 6876, 7282, 7437, 9813]
Primera posición en que aparece la mediana de la matriz: (2, 0)
```

Muestra cuando `cantidad_fila = 3` y `cantidad_columnas=2`:

```
Matriz:
 [[8257, 1526], [4050, 5836], [3309, 4283]]
Máximo valor de la matriz: 8257
Primera posición en que aparece el máximo valor: (0, 0)
Mínimo valor de la matriz: 1526
Primera posición en que aparece el mínimo valor: (0, 1)
Mediana de la matriz: 4166.5
[8257, 1526, 4050, 5836, 3309, 4283]
[1526, 3309, 4050, 4283, 5836, 8257]
Primera posición en que aparece la mediana de la matriz: La mediana fue calculada, por tanto, no tiene una posición en la matriz
```